# sharepoint 2010 cannot edit list item after approved

Tags: workflow, error, custom, content-approval

Working on a custom approval workflow, in which:

1. A form is filled out, and
2. Then the item is sent to an approver via email.
3. Approver views item, and chooses approve/reject from the ribbon.
4. Item steps into another workflow on edit, sends email to requester to add some details.
5. Requestor clicks link and clicks edit item in ribbon.... "boom"

Here is the error I get....

> Error An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: 0c7d2d68-9a76-4f00-aa81-f80eae59c16e
>
> Date and Time: 2/21/2012 1:36:34 PM

**I can edit the item prior to the initial approval, but can't edit after it is approved by the approver.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was there was a workflow that had started and was unable to be edited until the workflow was finished.